# Change background of row in PrefefenceActivity

Tags: android, selector, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, preference

I have a problem with Preference, I can't change the background of row(checkboxpreference, edittextpreference,..) .
anyone know this function in PreferenceActivity.

Tone of thanks,
Regards,

Comment: In your layout xml for the preferences, can you do android:background=    ?

Comment: I don't see that command.

Comment: Please share your layout xml for the PreferenceActivity in the original post.